# Push Up Fragment content when keyboard is activated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've searched it everywhere, and I've come up wrapping all my content inside a ScrollView, and setting the keyboard this way:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

But when I enable the keyboard by tapping the EditText, all the content gets pushed up except for a TextView in the Top part, why is that?

---

### XML Layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.NameSelection"
    android:background="#e0ab18">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/whoMaster"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/master"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/names"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/names" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/finish"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/names"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
        android:layout_below="@+id/names"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RelativeLayout try to use Linear Layout after scrollView.Set Orientation to  Vertical.

Comment: Take a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38995586/6489557) I've opened to see my new XML Code