# LinearLayout, layout_gravity not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to design a LinearLayout within a ScrollView, as the whole content will be pushed up when the keyboard will be activated.

---

### XML code I'm having issues with:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.NameSelection"
    android:background="#e0ab18">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/whoMaster"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/master"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/finish"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#e0ab18"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

What I don't understand is why the buttons inside the second `LinearLayout` don't get respectively on the `start` and o the `end` of the `LinearLayout`.

Thus, I'd like to have this final design, but I don't know how to achieve this using a LinearLayout:
[image: Final achievement]

Comment: Have you tried using android:gravity=""?

Comment: @Eenvincible any property with `android:propertyName` describes how the view will handle said property within itself. Any property with name `android:layout_propertyName` means its *requesting* the immediate parent container for that property.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

You can apply multiple gravity attributes by doing something like

```
android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

To align the element itself in it's parent you have to use `android:layout_gravity` to align the content of the element, say the text in a textview, you use `android:gravity`

When you need extra space between your elements it's not necessary to give the element a more than needed height like you did with the `EditText`. Simply add a `<Space>`element to provide lightweight empty spaces in your layout.

This is how I applied it to your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#e0ab18"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  tools:context="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.NameSelection">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="@string/whoMaster"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/names"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/master"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>


        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/finish"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="@string/finish"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Its always helpful for OP and other visitors to point out what you changed and how it affected the output.

Comment: Absolutely a great work! May I ask you to take a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38992856/6489557) I've opened before this one? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

Add this in your AndroidManifest file in respective activity.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_gravity` is intended to use with `FrameLayout` and defines the positioning of an element with `layout_gravity` set inside the enclosing `FrameLayout`. For `LinearLayout` it'll be simply ignored

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e0ab18"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.NameSelection">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="who is master"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/names"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="master's name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="next"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="back"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/finish"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="finish"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Check if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some modification in your `Layout`. Some modification in first `Linear Layout` changes in `weights and gravity`. And same also in second `Linear Layout`.

`Please apply this modified code in your XML`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e0ab18"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Who's The Master"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/names"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Master"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Back"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="#e0ab18" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

**Here is screen.**

[image]

Comment: You can at-least give an appreciation by up-vote to my answer if it's somewhere helpful to you. Check your OP and check my answer i have given exactly what you want in OP.